# Assure, make sure vs get sure

Tags: verbs

I was wondering if you could let me know that which one of the three choices in the following self-made scenario doesn't sound natural and why:

> - Last night I went to her home. She was so sad. I immediately found out that something has happened. I asked her what's wrong with you? She said I broke up with Dany (her boyfriend). She was crying all that time. I spoke to her and after a long conversation when I was telling her my own love story, she calmed down and fell asleep on the sofa. When I .............. that everything was OK, I left there.
>
> a) assured
>
> b) made sure
>
> c) got sure

For me, they all sound OK grammatically but I have no idea if they do semantically to you as natives.

Comment: I think _made sure_ is right. It is an idiom which means **to become absolutely certain**. _Assure_ is a transitive verb. So, it follows object always. And here there is no object. And  "got sure" is ungrammatical, I think.

Comment: You can use **assure** reflexively.  "When I *assured myself* that everything was OK...."  You can also say "When I was sure that...."

Comment: "I got sure" sounds very non-fluent to this native speaker.  In general, I would recommend learners avoid "got *adjective*" unless you're really sure you're using it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Use one of the options :

```
When I *made sure* that everything was OK, I left there.
```

2) You can restructure the sentence as :

```
When I **was assured** that everything was OK, I left.
```

(no need of there)

Comment: Thank you very much, Shruti, but could you please tell me if the pronoun "there" sound wrong grammatically or somehow else or it just seems to be redundant?

Comment: Personally, when I read the sentence with 'there' in this context, it sounds unnecessary and redundant. You just left the place, that's it.

Answer (score 1):

> I spoke to her and after a long conversation when I was telling her my own love story, she calmed down and fell asleep on the sofa. When I .............. that everything was OK, I left there.

*Assure X* means "to convince X that everything is OK."  It needs an object though (and does not default to reflexive if no object is specified like some other verbs), so while you could put *assure her* in the blank you cannot put just *assure*.  You can say *was assured that X* to mean that you were confident that X happened.

*Made sure* means "to have caused to be sure", and it fits in the above sentence.  This is what you want to say.

*Got X* can mean "to have become X".  It's rarely used with *sure*, an example would be this:

> So as time went on, I was scared, but eventually after talking to him, I got sure he wasn't going to kill me, so then I had the courage to run away.

It doesn't mean "you fixed it" in the same sense that *make sure* does.

Comment: This native speaker really doesn't like "got sure".  It sounds very non-fluent to me.  I'm having trouble explaining a rule for using "got", but I think in general we only use it for things that kind of happen to us as though from the outside: Over the summer I got taller; I waited for him so long I got hungry; I got ripped off by that sleazy salesman.  But not "I got sure"